# How to use multiple data.frame objects in one selectInput on shiny/ggplot2 app

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I am using R 3.2.3 through RStudio Version 0.99.491, on Windows 10 64bit... I am creating a ggplot2 shiny app, that displays a bubble chart. I don't understand the error messages I'm getting except for the fact that it's about inputs:

```
    Warning in validateSelected(selected, choices, inputId) :  
    'selected' must be the values instead of names of 'choices' for the input 'month'

    Warning: Error in ..stacktraceon..: object 'input' not found
    Stack trace (innermost first):

    1: shiny::runApp
    Error in ..stacktraceon..({ : object 'input' not found
```

here is the [data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FHVT2FMh5lW6Vx_KDwI-ZA2nSgWrOLkdRqEtoWT6qbU/edit?usp=sharing) that I am using. Here is the code

UI

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)

vars = c("april" = "April","may" = "May","june" = "June","july" = "July")

shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(    
sidebarPanel(
  selectInput("month", "Month", vars, selected = "april")),
mainPanel(plotOutput("plot")

)))
```

SEVER

```
library(shiny) 
library(leaflet)



melt_april <- melt(april)
names(april) = c('departure', 'stop', 'frequency')
melt_may <- melt(may)
names(may) = c('departure', 'stop', 'frequency')
melt_june <- melt(june)
names(june) = c('departure', 'stop', 'frequency')
melt_july <- melt(july)
names(july) = c('departure', 'stop', 'frequency')

 monthBy <- input$month




shinyServer( function(input, output){
observe({
  output$plot <- renderPlot({


     p <- ggplot(monthBy, aes(x = departure, y =stop, size = frequency, color = frequency)) + 
      geom_point()+
      scale_colour_gradient(low="white",high="orange")+

    print(p)

  )
})
```

})

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I think you might need

```
 monthBy <- input$month
```

inside the `shinyServer` function.

Comment: Thank you so much!  The app didn't crash! which is progress.  It gave me an error instead of the plot: `ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class character`  But does it mean class like data.frame?

Comment: yes! input$month is returning a string. I take it you want the dataframe with the name of that string? You could do something awkward like this: `eval(as.name(monthBy))` to get the actual data frame, but I think there's probably better ways.

Comment: Shiny is tricky to debug. Make sure you understand all the code you want to put into the app and it all runs before you start putting into Shiny.

Comment: Actually, that reminds me of a blog I wrote recently: http://mhairihmcneill.com/blog/2016/05/02/shiny-tips.html hopefully some of the tips might help a bit :)

Comment: The `eval(as.name(monthBy))` worked!  I gave it a name and it worked!!!! wooooo!!!! How do I accept your answer, do you have to change it to include the eval(as.name script?

Comment: No, I think the answer should stay as it is. I've answered your first question, so users with the same error message should find the answer as it is helpful. But clicking the accept answer button would be nice :)

Comment: Could I intrude on you a little more, What would you classify the `monthBy <- input$month` and `eval(as.name(monthBy))` line as?  This isn't the first time I've had trouble with this part of a reactive shiny app and I want to study the basics and documentation of the packages that I work with so that I can better understand what I am doing.  I just don't have a name for it.

Comment: The chapter is advanced R about non-standard evaluation might be a good plae to start: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html